# Summary of a conditional statement

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, func

How do I summarize the following conditional statement?

```
private static Func<T_Users, bool> GetFunc(short no = -1, decimal country = -1)
{
    Func<T_Users, bool> exp;

    if (no == -1 && countryNo != -1)
    { 
        exp = t => t.Country == country;
    }

    if (no != -1 && countryNo == -1)
    {
        exp = t => t.No == no;
    }

    if (no != -1 && countryNo != -1)
    {
        exp = t => t.No == no && t.Country == countryNo;
    }

    if (no == -1 && countryNo == -1)
    {
        exp = t => t.No != no && t.Country != countryNo;
    }
    return exp;
}
```

Condition number is high. This is not true. I think there is a right way, but I do not know. I have no idea to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It took the C# team a while to add support for default arguments.  They probably had the code in this question in mind.  You certainly won't get a warning about cyclomatic complexity from:

```
private static Func<T_Users, bool> GetFunc() {
    return new Func<T_Users, bool>((t) => t.No == -1 && t.Country == -1);
}
private static Func<T_Users, bool> GetFunc(short no) {
    return new Func<T_Users, bool>((t) => t.No == no && t.Country == -1);
}
private static Func<T_Users, bool> GetFunc(decimal country) {
    return new Func<T_Users, bool>((t) => t.No == -1 && t.Country == country);
}
private static Func<T_Users, bool> GetFunc(short no, decimal country) {
    return new Func<T_Users, bool>((t) => t.No == no && t.Country == country);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move the `if`-statements into the lambda function, like this:

```
Func<T_Users, bool> GetFunc(short no = -1, decimal country = -1)
{
    return t => (no == -1 || t.No == no)
             && (countryNo == -1 || t.Country == countryNo);
}
```

However, I would use *nullable* `short?` and `decimal?` instead (note the question marks), since `null` is ideally suited to represent a missing or undefined value:

```
Func<T_Users, bool> GetFunc(short? no = null, decimal? country = null)
{
    return t => (no == null || t.No == (short)no)
             && (countryNo == null || t.Country == (decimal)countryNo);
}
```

Note: this does *not* exactly do the same as your code, because I suspect your code has an error. Your final `if`-statement is:

```
if (no == -1 && countryNo == -1)
{
    exp = t => t.No != no && t.Country != countryNo;
}
```

...but I think you meant:

```
if (no == -1 && countryNo == -1)
{
    // If 'no' and 'countryNo' are unspecified, anything is valid.
    exp = t => true;
}
```

And I wrote the above code with that in mind.

Final remark: use more descriptive names than `no`. I can't tell what `no` is from only the code you posted, and after a while you won't be able to tell either.